# How to collect an iterator into an exiting container?

Tags: arrays, iterator, julia, allocation

If I have a iterators, say `a=1:10` and an array that I've already allocated (`x = zeros(10)`), how can I collect my array into the container without allocating a new array?

E.g. does something like `collect!(x, a)` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
copyto!(x, 1:10)
```

Filling the void here to 30 characters

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
x .= (1:10)
```

.........